# Capture everything before second slash - regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
/youtube.com/videos/cats
/google.com/images/dogs
```

I'm trying to find a regex formula that will allow me to capture the text up to the second slash (ignoring the rest of the string)

SO it would look like this

```
/youtube.com/
/google.com/
```

For reference I am using Python 3.7

I have tried positive lookbehinds and the closest I got was this:
`[^/]/`

Any help appreciated

Comment: `re.match(r'^/[^/]*/', your_string)`?

Comment: I am trying to capture the first part of the string - not match anything - just trying to remove all information after the second slash 0 so using str.replace(regex pattern, ' ') - this would add a space - your answer only pulls information from after second slash (which is what I want to remove if that makes sense)

Comment: `'/'.join(yourstring.split("/",3)[:2])`?

Comment: @PatrickArtner is there a purely regex answer to this?

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes I have tried using this - but the thing is trying to capture the first section of /youtube.com/ and not the rest as that is all i want to keep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex I provided in a comment will work. By matching the start of the string with `re.match()`, you can extract the area that was matched as a group.

```
>>> your_string = '/google.com/images/dogs'
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'^/[^/]*/', your_string).group(0)
'/google.com/'
```

Here's how the regex is laid out:

- `^` start of string
- `/` a slash character
- `[^/]*` any number of characters that are not slashes
- `/` another slash character

So this regex will capture the first slash, the second slash, and the text in between them, as long as they come at the beginning of the string.

---

If you were to want the rest of the string, ignoring this first part, you could just add a capture group afterwards and pull group 1 (the first captured group) instead of 0 (the entire match):

```
>>> re.match(r'^/[^/]*/(.*)$', your_string).group(1)
'images/dogs'
```

Comment: How would this work in my case with 2 urls? it seems that re.match does not work multiple strings in a list - or i may be wrong?

Comment: Can you not just call it multiple times, once for each element of the list? Like in a list comprehension.

Comment: never thought of that one - bit rusty on Python, been quite a while since using it - thanks and will do!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use re.sub to remove the text after the 2nd slash then perhaps the following will help.

```py
import re

data = '''\
/youtube.com/videos/cats
/google.com/images/dogs
'''
pattern = re.compile(r'^(/[^/]+/).+?$', re.MULTILINE)

print(pattern.sub(r'\1', data))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
/youtube.com/videos/cats
/google.com/images/dogs
```

**RegEx**

```
/.*?/    : [1]
/        : First slash
 .*?     : Non-greedy match anything
    /    : Second slash

    /* Output:
          FULL MATCH
      1>  /youtube.com/
      2>  /google.com/
    */



/(.*?)/  : [2] : Same as [1] BUT captures the text between the slashes as a group {symbol: (...)}
^/(.*?)/ : [3] : Same as [2] BUT specifies match must be at start of string {symbol: ^}

    /* Output:
          FULL MATCH           CAPTURE GROUP
      1>  /youtube.com/        youtube.com
      2>  /google.com/         google.com
    */


(/(.*?)(?=$|/))  : [4] : Captures text between all slashes
** FLAGS: MULTILINE
    ** Unless passed in individually (i.e. one expression per URL)

    /* Output:
          Full MATCH          CAPTURE GROUP
      1>  /youtube.com        youtube.com
      2>  /videos             videos
      3>  /cats               cats
      4>  /google.com/        google.com
      5>  /images             images
      6>  
    */



/(.*?)(?=$|/)    : [5] : Same as [4] BUT doesn't capture leading slashes
** FLAGS: MULTILINE
    ** Unless passed in individually (i.e. one expression per URL)

    /* Output:
          FULL MATCH
      1>  youtube.com
      2>  videos
      3>  cats
      4>  google.com
      5>  images
      6>  dogs
    */
```

**Example 1**

Match text between first two slashes. Singular input.

```
import re
regex    = r"/(.*?)/"
test_str = "/youtube.com/videos/cats"
matches  = re.findall(regex, test_str)

// RESULT: matches == ['youtube.com']
```

**Example 2**

Match text between first two slashes. Multiline input.

```
import re
regex    = r"/(.*?)/"
test_str = """
/youtube.com/videos/cats
/google.com/images/dogs
"""
matches  = re.findall(regex, test_str)

//RESULT : matches == ['youtube.com', 'google.com']
```

**Example 3**

Match text between all slashes. Singular input.

```
import re
regex    = r"/(.*?)(?=$|/)"
test_str = "/youtube.com/videos/cats"
matches  = re.findall(regex, test_str)

// RESULT: matches == ['youtube.com', 'videos', 'cats']
```

**Example 4**

Match text between all slashes. Multiline input.

```
import re
regex = r"/(.*?)(?=$|/)"
test_str = """
/youtube.com/videos/cats
/google.com/videos/cats
"""
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

//RESULT: matches == ['youtube.com', 'videos', 'cats', 'google.com', 'videos', 'cats']
```